# Subtitute Parts/Rows Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to create relationship in Postgresql that allows me to have ‘substitute’ parts. For example, parts with id 1, 2 and 4 are substitutes.

One way to do this would be to setup a sub_id field and fill that with the substitute part’s id. But as you can see from the dataset below, a simple query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM part 
WHERE sub_id = 1
```

would not return all the substitute parts for part AA (part A2 would be missed). How can I ensure all the substitute parts are catered for?

I know that if the sub_id was 1 for part A2, all would be good. However, it’s possible that in real world usage the users end up making a mistake and that would return the wrong result.

```
id  part    sub_id
1   AA      1
2   A       1
3   B       NULL
4   A2      2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a different approach.

I don't know what your needs are but this is a general idea:

Set up a table that define a part "group":

```
partgid, part type,   partg name 
   1       A          Engine for A319
   2       B          Wheel for A319
```

code:

```
Create Table partgroup
(
 partgid int,
 parttype text,
 partgname text 
);
```

then define parts in the group:

```
partid  partgid   partname       manufacturerid
 12       1         Engine X319       800
 13       1         Engine XL319      800
 14       1         Engine XFR319     784
 15       2         Wheel F1111       341
```

code:

```
Create Table parts
(
 partid  int,        
 partgid int,
 partname text,
 manufacturerid int 
);
```

then you can access all parts in a specific group in a simple query:

By ID:

```
select *
from parts
where partgid='ID'
```

By name:

```
select *
from parts
left join partgroup on (partgroup.partgid=parts.partgid)
where partgroup.parttype= 'TYPE NAME'
```